# Ranking - Select corresponding column values to a MAX(column) value

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a gameplay table with the following fields:
`user_id, level, clear_time`

There are some N number of levels and the table keeps track of when user crosses a certain level. Now, I need to rank user based on two constraints: `level` and `clear_time`. As it is obvious, user in higher level stands ahead but when more than one user is in the same level, `clear_time` is what decides who is ahead i.e. the one to first clear that level stands ahead. Following is what I tried which is not working the way I want to. Level ordering works fine but `clear_time` is messed up.

```
SELECT 
    u.*,
    @rank := @rank + 1 rank
FROM
    ( SELECT
        t1.user_id user_id,
        MAX(t1.level) level,
        t1.clear_time clear_time,
        t2.username username
    FROM 
            gameplay t1
    INNER JOIN
        users t2
    ON
        ( t1.user_id = t2.id )
    GROUP BY
        user_id
    ORDER BY
        level DESC,
        clear_time ASC
    ) u
JOIN
    ( SELECT @rank := 0 ) r
```

I see the problem is MAX(level) doesn't get its corresponding clear_time. I can't get it done.
Analyzing the results, I see the corresponding fields to `MAX(t1.level)` value are not selected. How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like `gameplay` has multiple entries per `user_id`. That is: an entry for level `x` and for level `y` both with the same `user_id` and you want to select the row with the highest level and the corresponding value of `clear_time`, but `MAX` will only select the maximum level in the group, and not the value of `clear_time` from the same row.

You can do this with an additional `JOIN` on `gameplay`. Edit: here's an example I setup:

```
MariaDB [test]> select * from gameplay;
+---------+---------------------+-------+
| user_id | clear_time          | level |
+---------+---------------------+-------+
|       1 | 2014-11-08 11:22:25 |     1 |
|       1 | 2014-11-09 11:22:40 |     2 |
+---------+---------------------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [test]> select * from users;
+----+----------+
| id | username |
+----+----------+
|  1 | foo      |
+----+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

The row we would want to select in this example is `level=2`, `clear_time=2014-11-09 11:22:40`. Here's my query:

```
MariaDB [test]> SELECT t1.user_id, t2.username, t1.level, t3.clear_time
FROM 
   (SELECT user_id, max(level) as level FROM gameplay GROUP BY user_id) as t1
INNER JOIN (users t2, gameplay t3)
ON t1.user_id=t2.id AND t3.level=t1.level AND t3.user_id=t1.user_id;

+---------+----------+-------+---------------------+

| user_id | username | level | clear_time          |
+---------+----------+-------+---------------------+
|       1 | foo      |     2 | 2014-11-09 11:22:40 |
+---------+----------+-------+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: but wait, @GregBoswer, this is causing some user_id's to repeat.

Comment: What do the duplicates look like? The same `level` and `user_id`, but different `clear_time` (multiple entries in `gameplay` for a given `user_id` and `level`)?

Comment: @GregBoswer : Okay, that was caused due to the repeated user_id's. Thanks. :)